# What is indirect and virtual subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x

## In [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) says:

> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, **indirect or virtual**) **subclass** thereof.
>   I am confused about these two concepts.

## Question 1: So what is indirect subclass?

Is it like

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    pass
```

class C is indirect subclass of A?

## Question 2: What is virtual subclass?

Comment: On the page you quoted, "virtual" is a link. Try following the link.

Comment: Oh. Thanks, now I know that 'virtual' is abstract base class. I was confused why it links to 'abstract base class' before.